# Animated Scrollview

Tags: android, button, scrollview

While going through a IOS app in my company, I saw the buttons set in a horizontal scroll view in a animated manner which looked really good. When asked the IOS developers they said it is a pre built in function available in xcode. I want to know whether it can be achieved in Android.

Details regarding the scroll view.

There are buttons when scrolled over revolves around. To be more precise it moves in the anti-clockwise direction but doesn't disappear from view.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want or it may help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot GOLDEE this is the one i exactly needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If my understanding is correct about your question, We have `HorizontalScrollView` to achieve that in android. You have to do your own animation while scroll. There is no in build animations while scrolling.

Please go through the following [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rethinavel but this is not the view. the button or the view which is scrolled can be still seen the screen. Its like a clock in the 3D. if 6 is facing us we can still see 9 12 and 3 but in background. similar to that.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot please?

Comment: I don't have access to that.

Comment: upload your image to any site and comment the url here

Comment: Rethinavel the answer was answered by GOLDEE. Thanks for Helping.